# Not sure how to test a line of code in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I am having touble testing the throw command after the  if (command[0] == '(')).  The if statment I think means that if the first char in command does not  equel ) throw an error.  I have tried a several statments without a ) but have still not been able to execute the throw command.  Any ideas.

```
private double ParseTerm(ref string command)
    {
        double returnValue=0;
        if (command.Length != 0)
        {
         if (command[0] == '('))
            {
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);   // skip the open paren
                returnValue= ParseExpr(ref command);
                if (command[0] != ')')                              // make sure there is a close paren for each open parenthesis
                    throw new System.FormatException();
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);   // skip the close paren
            } 
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here is ParseExpr

```
private double ParseExpr(ref string command)
    {
        double op, op2;

        if (command == "")                              // Handle the empty expression case
            return 0;

        op = ParseFactor(ref command);                  // parse left side of expression

        if (command != "")                              // if a right side exists, parse it
        {               

            if (command[0] == '+')                      // test for '+'
            {           
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);   // skip to +

                if (command.Length == 0)    
                    throw new System.FormatException();     // no right hand side operator

                op2 = ParseExpr(ref command);               // parse remainder of the expression
                op +=  op2;
            } 
            else if (command[0] == '-')
            {                   
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);
                if (command.Length == 0)
                    throw new System.FormatException();
                op2 = ParseExpr(ref command);           
                op -=  op2;
            } 
        }
        return op;
    }


    private double ParseFactor(ref string command)
    {
        double op, op2;
        op = ParseExp(ref command);
        if (command != "")
        {               
            if (command[0] == '*')
            {                   
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);
                if (command.Length == 0)
                    throw new System.FormatException();
                op2 = ParseFactor(ref command);         
                op *=  op2;
            } 
            else if (command[0] == '/' || command[0] == '\\')
            {                   
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);
                if (command.Length == 0)
                    throw new System.FormatException();
                op2 = ParseFactor(ref command);     

                if (op2 == 0)                                   // don't allow divide 0
                    throw new System.DivideByZeroException();   // the division operation won't return
                op /=  op2;                                     // throw the exception since we are using doubles
            }               
            else if (command[0] == '%')
            {                   
                command = command.Substring(1,command.Length -1);
                if (command.Length == 0)
                    throw new System.FormatException();
                op2 = ParseFactor(ref command);                             
                op = (int)op % (int)op2;
            } 
        }
        return op;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show  ParseExpr method?

Comment: It depends on what `ParseExpr()` does...

Comment: Does `ParseFactor()` modify `command`?

Comment: You need to step through your program in your debugger. Follow each statement so that you can verify what is happening, and compare that against your expectation. When you get to the line of code that isn't throwing a FormatException when you expect it to, you should be able to easily point to why. The key is to step through the code, follow it as it executes.

Comment: I don't think ParseFactor() modifies command to what I am trying to do, but I am posting it anyway

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, tried that it was not helpfull

Comment: How did it not help? You're looking for a first character value of `')'`. If that is not there, you expect an exception. If you step through the code, you should be able to *at all times* follow the flow, see what the variable's value is, and at the point you get to the line you're trying to see execute, *it should be no suprise* what happens. If stepping through the code isn't helping, you're not paying proper attention.

Comment: Same question about `ParseExp()`, and any other method that gets called and is passed `command` by ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean a UnitTest? If yes:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
public void ParseTerm_when_the_last_char_is_not_a_close_parenthesis_should_throw_FormatException()
{
    //Call the method here:
    ParseTerm("(some string without close parenthesis");
}
```